# spring-boot-starter-web enum and deserialize fail

Tags: java, spring-boot, enums, gson, spring-web

I want deserialize a Object but json data is a string and the element of my object is not a string but a enum (of string).

My Object (want deserialize):

```
public enum ResponseStatus {

    SUCCESS, ERROR, WARNING, NO_ACCESS

}

public class SessionResponse extends OperationResponse {
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, value = "")
    private SessionItem item;

    public SessionResponse() {
        super();
    }

    public SessionItem getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(SessionItem item) {
        this.item = item;
    }

}

public class OperationResponse {

    @ApiModelProperty(required = true)
    private ResponseStatus operationStatus;
    private String operationMessage;

    public ResponseStatus getOperationStatus() {
        return operationStatus;
    }

    public void setOperationStatus(ResponseStatus operationStatus) {
        this.operationStatus = operationStatus;
    }

    public String getOperationMessage() {
        return operationMessage;
    }

    public void setOperationMessage(String operationMessage) {
        this.operationMessage = operationMessage;
    }

}
```

I use this web client:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpEntity<Login> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Login("demo", "demo"), headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/session", request, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

console:

```
{
  "operationStatus" : "SUCCESS",
  "operationMessage" : "Login Success",
  "item" : {
    "token" : "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI",
    "userId" : "demo",
    "firstName" : "Zinédine",
    "lastName" : "Zidane",
    "email" : "zzidane@mail.com",
    "roles" : [ ]
  }
}
```

But if I use

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpEntity<Login> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Login("demo", "demo"), headers);
ResponseEntity<SessionResponse> response = new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity("http://localhost:" + port + "/session", request, SessionResponse.class);
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

trace:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.xxx.xxx.model.session.SessionResponse]
```

**EDIT 1**

if I add gson deserializer just after, is it OK

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SessionResponse s = gson.fromJson(response.getBody(), SessionResponse.class);
System.out.println(s.getItem().getLastName());
```

is it possoble to use gson directly in TestRestTemplate().postForEntity ?